# Как не инициализировать карту ymaps.ready, если сервисы яндекса не доступны

Tags: yandex-maps-api

Есть классический код типа

```
   $(document).ready(function () {
      ymaps.ready(function () {
        map = ymapCreate('map');
        ymapClear(map);
        ...
        ymapFitObjectsIntoMap(map);
      });
   }
```

и есть подключаемый скрипт

```
<script defer src="//api-maps.yandex.ru/2.1/?apikey=<...>&lang=ru-RU"></script>
```

Все работает отлично. Однако вчера вырубили инет и при тесте в локальной сети получилось, что скрипт яндекса не доступен. В результате ymaps не инициализировался и все, что было после упало с классическим сообщением *ymaps is undefined*. Попытки обернуть **ymasp.ready** в условие типа **if (ymaps)** или **if (ymaps !== undefined)** провалились. ympas начинает существовать только после загрузки яндекс-скрипта. Оно бы может и фиг бы с ним, но чисто гипотетически сервисы яндекса могут упасть, стало быть отгниет и мой сайт, а надо, чтобы жил без карты.

Нагуглил здесь же предложение использовать **window.ymaps**. С ним получилось обернуть в такой код

```
   $(document).ready(function () {
    if (window.ymaps) {
      ymaps.ready(function () {
        map = ymapCreate('map');
        ymapClear(map);
        ...
        ymapFitObjectsIntoMap(map);
      });
    }
  }
```

С ним все заработало как задумано. Т.е. при имитации недоступности сервисов яндекса, карта не инициализируется, другие скрипты на странице не падают и все работает без карты.

Вопрос: **а правильно ли я сделал или может есть какие-то более умные способы?** А то из меня джаваскриптер тот еще...

Comment: Уберите вы этот defer из вызова API. Вероятность смерти вашего сайта много больше недоступности Яндекса. А без загрузки API не запустится и скрипт карты. Остальной же код будет работать. Зачем вы всё усложняете?

Comment: @YaCor', defer здесь роли не играет. Ну или я не вижу разницы. А суть проста - я слишком давно живу как и мое дело, а вот масса гораздо более крупных и стабильных бизнесов давно мертва и про них никто не помнит. Я не признаю облака, cdn и прочую муть. Все должно быть у тебя. Все, что не получается притащить к себе, должно быть изолировано так, чтобы при недоступности все твое продолжало работать. Т.е. API карт не доступен, значит пусть мое работает без карты. Сегодня яндекс есть, а завтра его нет. Я не желаю оказаться на месте юзеров матлаба из-за левой пятки яндекса, гугла и т.п.

Comment: Понял вас. Но в этом случае Яндекс предлагает более просто вроде бы вариант – параметр onload. Как только API загрузится, выполнит функцию которая будет отвечать за создание карты – тот же init() в примерах их песочницы.

Comment: Пробовал с onload(), но что-то не пошло. Видимо надо вытащить часть кода из под $(document).ready(), но тогда ломается что-то иное. Опыта на JS пока не хватает(( Оставлю пока так, как есть, тем более, что решение вроде бы рабочее. Но другие предложения с удовольствием рассмотрю! @YaCor' Вам большое спасибо за внимание и помощь!